# how to check if app's orientation is fixed on android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to figure out how to check if the top acitivity(currently used by the user)'s orientation is fixed. Let's say user is using instagram and as you know instagram's orientation is always portrait. Is there a way for me to check if the orientation is unchangable/fixed? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to fix it in your app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check it programmatically.  Since fixed also means portrait

```
     getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

     int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
     if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
         // Todo portrait
     } else {
        // Todo landscape
     }
```